# why does find command use {} for a placeholder variable?

Tags: find

I'm curious as to why `find` uses `{}` as the syntax for variable substitution (e.g., as in `find . -name "*~" -exec rm {} \;`). It's a rather unusual syntax, and I don't know any other programs or languages that use `{}` as a placeholder.

Comment: xargs also uses it, but that might be a more recent addition. What other programs use placeholders?

Comment: @jordanm as far as I know, `xargs` does not use it, it is just the standard value for the `xargs` `-I` option but that is just convention, the `man` page does not indicate that `{}` is reserved, it just uses it as an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is in your question.  Other commands don't use `{}` as a placeholder.  That way you can still use `find`'s `-exec` option without having to worry about a bunch of nonsense to escape or work around the fact that a command uses `{}` just like find does.